# SharePoint Doc Library - JSON changes color of text in hyperlink column

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, hyperlink, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a hyperlink column which displays a light blue color, until I add some conditional formatting to indent child documents.

My script is:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "margin-left": "=if([$IsChild] == 'Yes','40px','0px')",
    "width": "500px"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "[$Title]",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "[$Title_x0020_Links]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This works exactly how I want it, but when applied, it darkens the shade of blue for the column links. Is there a way I can change the color to light blue within this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add color to hyperlink like below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "margin-left": "=if([$IsChild] == 'Yes','40px','0px')",
    "width": "500px"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "[$Title]",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "[$Title_x0020_Links]"
      },
      "style": {
        "color": "lightblue"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can add any color at below line as per your requirements:

```
"color": "lightblue"
```

You can use HEX color code as well like:

```
"color": "#87ceeb"
```

You can find some shades of blue & their HEX codes at: [Shades of Blue](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/colors/shades-of-blue/)

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: Hi @Chris, did you try this? Is it working for you?

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you.  I ended up also adding script to remove the text-decoration too, which removed the underline to the hyperlinks.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. (As you already know) underline of hyperlinks can be removed easily by adding `"text-decoration": "none"` inside `style` property (leaving this comments for other users reading this thread in future).